# Get-ADGroup returns different ObjectGUID than dsquery

Tags: powershell, active-directory, dsquery

Can someone explain how to get the ObjectGUID the same as is returned from dsquery except using powershell?

As an example.

Powershell

```
Get-ADGroup "MyGroup" -Properties ObjectGUID
32359aec-2e77-4b0c-b525-3e9a39083314
```

dsquery (application uses DSQuery don't have the command it uses)

```
7Jo1MncuDEu1JT6aOQgzFA==
```

Edit - For clarity, I want to query the AD Group in powershell and get the DSQuery result for ObjectGUID.  I do not want the powershell result for ObjectGUID.

Comment: "*Blippity Bloppity Blit* - you're base64 string is now a GUID": `[guid]::new([convert]::FromBase64String('7Jo1MncuDEu1JT6aOQgzFA=='))`

Comment: I want the other way.  I want to input the powershell ObjectGUID and get the one that DSget returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output from `dsquery` is the raw underlying binary GUID, base64-encoded.

To convert between the two formats:

```
# GUID to base64
$guidInstance = [guid]::new('32359aec-2e77-4b0c-b525-3e9a39083314')
[convert]::ToBase64String($guidInstance.ToByteArray())

# base64 to GUID
$binaryGUID = [convert]::FromBase64String('7Jo1MncuDEu1JT6aOQgzFA==')
[guid]::new($binaryGUID)
```